# How to understand this POD rule

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

```
struct A
{
  int i;
};

struct B
{
 B(){} 
 int i;
}
```

Hi,all

I know "POD means Plain Old Data type which by definition cannot have user-defined constructor".
But I can't understand why this rule is effective when "definition have an user-defined default-con".

There is no difference of their memory layout.Why type A is POD,but not B?

Comment: Add a language flag. C++, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are POD types in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

Comment: Because the language says so? POD means the state is expressed entirely by the members, but having a user-defined constructor means there's additional state in the logic of the constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is simple.  Once you define a constructor (any
constructor), the language assumes that the class needs some
sort of initialization; that just copying the bits in its image
won't be sufficient to create a new instance.  And one of the
important characteristics of PODs is that they can be memcpy'ed.

In sum, the compiler does *not* look at the contents of a class
to determine whether it is POD or not (except to see if any of
the members are PODS).  It looks at whether you've defined anything
special which might affect the initialization, assignment or
destruction of those members.

Comment: A "trivially copyable" class in c++11 can be memcpy'd, and is allowed to have user-provided constructors.

Comment: @interjay  About "allowed to have user-provided constructors".Do you mean the user-provided constructors are using =default?

Comment: @LeonhartSquall: No, a trivially copyable class can have any constructor provided by the user (with non-default behavior) except for copy and move constructors.

Comment: @James Kanze When compiler cannot look at the contents it is really impossible to determine a class weather a POD type.But I think the compiler can obtain this context usually as you say "to see if any of the members are PODS".And I think this is a correct way instead of by finding a class weather having any constructor.

Comment: @interjay http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable  note one writes "Other than the other requirements, trivial constructor, assignment and destructor must be defined implicitly (not user-provided)".

Comment: @LeonhartSquall That sentence is written quite confusingly, and I assume it refers to the copy/move constructors mentioned above. It seems quite redundant anyway because a trivial constructor/destructor is by definition not user-provided. In any case, the standard (9p6) only mentions copy and move constructors, copy/move assignment operators, and the destructor.

Comment: @LeonhartSquall Consider a typical implementation of `std::string` or `std::vector`.  All of the members will have POD type, but the class itself is definitely not a POD.  The constructors, assignment operator, etc. define a number of invariants on the POD data, which must be maintained.

Comment: @interjay If you're referring to the change in the text of
§3.9/3, this is clearly an error in the standard, since it can
only be true up to a point: if the class has a non-trivial
destructor or assignment operator, the `memcpy` will not work.
(Of course, it's hard to imagine a class which needs
a non-trivial destructor or assignment operator, but can use
a trivial copy constructor.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I don't know what change in the text you are referring to. If a class has a non-trivial destructor or assignment operator then it isn't trivially copyable, and 3.9/3 doesn't apply. See 9/6 for requirements of a trivially copyable class.

Comment: @James Kanze So my understanding is: compiler will treat this class as 'C++ style' not POD type when the compiler meet a default constructor, becuase the compiler thinks the default constructor must do some special initialize work that belongs to C++, even though the default constructor doesn't do anything and actually the type of very member in the class is POD.Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @LeonhartSquall Yes, C++11 adds additional categories.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of [POD has been split into trivial and standardy-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/819272) concepts. You can query those properties through the standard type traits.

Class `B` is not POD because it is not trivial. It is not trivial because it has a user-provided default constructor. Either omit that or use the new C++11 `=default` syntax.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>

struct A
{
  int i;
};

struct B
{
 B(){} 
 int i;
};

struct C
{
 C() = default;
 int i;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<A>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivial<A>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_standard_layout<A>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<B>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivial<B>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_standard_layout<B>::value << "\n";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pod<C>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivial<C>::value << " ";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_standard_layout<C>::value << "\n";
}
```

[Online output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=eb1a05cbf3b33df697984c242565a167-a9c3f5b442fb879fd63f42e442814930):

```
true true true
false false true
true true true
```

Answer (score 1):

PODs allow the compiler to do certain optimizations. As a rule of thumb, a type is POD if the compiler is allowed to treat the `struct` the same way as a C-compiler would.

In particular, when initializing a POD struct, the compiler just needs to reserve memory of the appropriate *size*, it does not need to worry about *initialization*. Initialization can be requested explicitly by the programmer, but it never happens implicitly as could be the case with a user-defined constructor.

For example, a user-defined default constructor might require the data to get initialized to 0. In general, the default constructor might even have *arbitrary side effects* that the compiler needs to consider.

Comment: What, illustratively, is the difference between `malloc`ing and `new`ing? Doesn't `new A()` do initialization?

Comment: @JonathanWakely `new` performs initialization (usually by calling a constructor), `malloc` does not.

Comment: `new A` doesn't do initialization if `A` is POD, but `new A()` does do initialization even if `A` is POD.  My point is that your "analogy for illustrative purposes" isn't actually very illustrative, because I can "allocate memory for an array of POD structs" and still have the compiler initialize it.  There are better ways to define PODs than a flawed analogy.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I see your point. I was trying to make clear what I meant with the malloc/new analogy, but apparently it was still not clear enough. Rephrased the question accordingly.